# Xamarin Forms Application.Current Properties Backup on user Google Drive account

Tags: c#, xamarin, xamarin.forms, google-drive-api, google-drive-android-api

I want to store my Application.Current.Properties to user's Google Drive Account as backup. And Sync functionality from App to Drive and vice a versa.

I have searched and found very little info about it. But unable to take start as I am a newbie in using the user's Cloud storage.

So can anyone guide me how to achieve this? No such documentation or video tutorial found to do it from scratch. I need help.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Well this is sort of opinion based brother but what have you thought of? Are you going to save this properties as a text file? Or how? Are you going to json serialize it? You should have atleast basic understanding of what your plan will be.

Comment: @G.hakim I mentioned the goal in the question. And yes of course the file will be a text file or a xml file. And can be JSON serialization applied on it. But suggest the best method please? Do we require JSON serialization for simple text or xml file? which file format we can use with the simple and minimal implementation?

Comment: Of course, it can be JSON serialized as an `IDictionary<string,object>`, I am not sure if this is the best method but it sure is the easiest, other than that you can create a text file using `System.IO` after that uploading to GoogleDrive is a Task!